# setSession() not called?

Tags: java, session, configuration, struts2, struts2-interceptors

In my action class which implements `SessionAware`, its `setSession()` is not called.
I am receiving callback on `execute()` directly.

Following are some relevant details:

**Struts.xml**

```
<package name="profile" extends="struts-default" namespace="/profile">
    <result-types>
        <result-type name="dispatcher"
            class="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult"
            default="true" />
        <result-type name="tiles"
            class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"></result-type>
    </result-types>
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="authenticationinterceptor"
            class="interceptors.common.AuthenticationInterceptor"></interceptor>
        <interceptor-stack name="secureInterceptor">
            <interceptor-ref name="authenticationinterceptor"></interceptor-ref>
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <action name="staff" class="actions.profile.StaffProfileAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="secureInterceptor"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success" type="tiles">/profilestaff.tiles</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

**Action class**

```
public class StaffProfileAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {
    SessionMap<String, Object> sessionmap;

    public String execute() throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
        logger.info("StaffProfileAction->setSession");
        sessionmap = (SessionMap<String, Object>) session;

    }
}
```

I am not using any of the interceptor from the default stack. Do i need any interceptor to be added in order to receive callback on `setSession()`. Please point out my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need [`servletConfig`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/servlet-config-interceptor.html) interceptor.

> An interceptor which sets action properties based on the interfaces an action implements.

Because you implement `SessionAware` the interceptor should be on the stack to allow using a servlet session capabilities.

Comment: I was experiencing the same issue, that one line fixed it.

Comment: @GauravGupta I am having a doubt here, Servletconfig interceptor is already part of default stack right, why we need to add it again.And I also have one scenario where I am trying to create custom interceptor which implements sessionaware so that cross-cutting concerns like session management will be handled separately in interceptor

Comment: @Rikku121 Can you please help on above question?